# Why WordPressPCL on asp.net Post.CreateAsync Does not work?

Tags: c#, json, wordpress

i cant create a post using the version 2.0.1 on asp.net CORE

This is the Code:

```
var client = new WordPressClient( "http://sitioweb.com/wp-json/" );
client.Auth.UseBasicAuth( "username", "app_password" );        

var post = new Post() {
  Title = new Title( "ITCmx" ),
  Content = new Content( "Content PostCreate" )
};

var createdPost = await client.Posts.CreateAsync( post );
```

And get this error

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'WordPressPCL.Models.Post' because the type requires a JSON object
> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
> either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
> change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
> collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
> deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
> to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '',
> line 1, position 1.

I try on Postman and works fine

Could you please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data to json before sending

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post);

var createdPost = await client.Posts.CreateAsync( json);
```

Comment: Nop, i cant use it as string or json, because the datatype is "Post" from the WordPressPCL models